# How to group_by or get only one record of some row (QUERY)

Tags: oracle

I have a query that a i need to resolve.

**This is the query:**

```
SELECT
DISTINCT confirmation_no,
nationality_desc,
guest_first_name ||'  '||guest_name Guest_name,
adults,
children,
rate_code,
trace_on,
guest_rsv_traces.dept_id
FROM
guest_rsv_traces,
name_reservation 
WHERE
trace_on >= '04-SEP-19'
AND guest_rsv_traces.resv_name_id = name_reservation.resv_name_id
AND rate_code like 'ALL%'
AND resv_status not in ('CANCELLED')
AND guest_rsv_traces.dept_id not in ('TRF','OD')
```

**Actual output:**

```
145382  EE.UU   ZHIHUA  WU  1   0      ALLGR2N15    18/09/19    LOG
147811  China   NANCY  CHOW 2   0   ALLFIT4N25CR    29/10/19    HK
147811  China   NANCY  CHOW 2   0   ALLFIT4N25CR    31/10/19    HK
147811  China   NANCY  CHOW 2   0   ALLFIT4N25CR    01/11/19    HK
147813  China    EMIL  CHAN 2   0   ALLFIT4N25CR    28/10/19    HK
```

**Desired output:**

```
145382  EE.UU   ZHIHUA  WU  1   0      ALLGR2N15    18/09/19    LOG
147811  China   NANCY  CHOW 2   0   ALLFIT4N25CR    29/10/19    HK
147813  China    EMIL  CHAN 2   0   ALLFIT4N25CR    28/10/19    HK
```

**What i need?:** Get only one 'confirmation_no' per person (First column number).

**PLUS:** I would like to sum the 'adults' and 'children' too (
fourth and fifth column respectively). The result would be 5 adults and 0 children.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be good if you share the sample data and along with it the expected output too. Your question is quite confusing.

Comment: Please edit the question show a sample table of data.

Comment: @Tejash thanks, i edited the post, sorry about that.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i edited the post, take a look please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to get what you are trying to ask but when I see your question again, I thought that you need to know the usage of `group by` and I am trying to share small example and usage of `group by` as following.

```
SELECT
<any column from group by clause>,
Aggregate_function(<column which is not in group by clause>)
From
Table
Where..
Group by <columns on which group by is needed>
```

So taking the example where table contains following data:

```
Id  val
1   10
1   20
1   30
2   15
2   35
```

Following query will show you demo of group by

```
SELECT 
ID, -- column from group by clause 
MAX(VAL) AS MAX_VAL, -- aggregate function
MIN(VAL) AS MIN_VAL, -- aggregate function 
COUNT(1) AS CNT  -- aggregate function
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID; -- grouping column
```

Result:

```
ID MAX_VAL MIN_VAL CNT
1  30      10      3
2  35      15      2
```

Hope, This will help you in solving the problem.

Cheers!!

-- UPDATE --

As you have now provided the actual data, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONFIRMATION_NO,
    NATIONALITY_DESC,
    GUEST_NAME,
    ADULTS,
    CHILDREN,
    RATE_CODE,
    TRACE_ON,
    DEPT_ID,
    SUM(ADULTS) OVER()
    || ' ADULTS AND '
    || SUM(CHILDREN) OVER()
    || ' CHILDRENS' AS RESULT
FROM
( SELECT
    MAX(CONFIRMATION_NO) AS CONFIRMATION_NO, -- added max here
    NATIONALITY_DESC,
    GUEST_FIRST_NAME
    || '  '
    || GUEST_NAME GUEST_NAME,
    MAX(ADULTS) AS ADULTS,
    MAX(CHILDREN) AS CHILDREN,
    RATE_CODE,
    MIN(TRACE_ON) AS TRACE_ON,
    LISTAGG(GUEST_RSV_TRACES.DEPT_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS DEPT_ID -- added this listagg
FROM
    GUEST_RSV_TRACES,
    NAME_RESERVATION
WHERE....
..........
GROUP BY
--CONFIRMATION_NO, -- commented this
NATIONALITY_DESC,
GUEST_FIRST_NAME,
GUEST_NAME,
RATE_CODE
-- GUEST_RSV_TRACES.DEPT_ID -- removed this column from group by
);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks my friend, almost there, now i have a column name "RESULT" with the amount of adults and children. Sadly my initial problem ('confirmation_no' duplicates) still on. I attach you a pic: https://ibb.co/BC1dVHM

Comment: Almos there!! i can see just a couple of duplicates. Here the pic: https://ibb.co/4FvSBrC

Comment: Yeap, see now!!

Comment: a question dude, if i do the query with a WHERE BETWEEN from and to, it works fine, except when you query the same day on both, so what i did? i changed the query to a WHERE trace_on = '05-SEP-19' (it has two rows) but it doesn't work, do you know how could i fix it? maybe it's easy for you, if not i guess  i could create a new question. I will be tuned to your answer.

Comment: It will be appreciated if you ask new question to avoid mess.

Comment: i followed your advice dude, i would really like if you take a look. here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632738/query-between-not-working-if-it-has-the-same-date THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
confirmation_no, nationality_desc, guest_first_name ||' '||guest_name Guest_name, adults, children, rate_code, max(trace_on), max(guest_rsv_traces.dept_id)
 FROM guest_rsv_traces, name_reservation 
WHERE trace_on >= '04-SEP-19' 
AND guest_rsv_traces.resv_name_id = name_reservation.resv_name_id 
AND rate_code like 'ALL%' 
AND resv_status not in ('CANCELLED') 
AND guest_rsv_traces.dept_id not in ('TRF','OD')
group by confirmation_no, nationality_desc, guest_first_name ||' '||guest_name Guest_name, adults, children, rate_code
```

Comment: sorry for plaintext, i'm typing from a phone

Comment: Thanks for your query dude, sadly it comes with duplicates :/ here the pic: https://ibb.co/PCDs4rt

Comment: done, check now! after that - if you need to do a sum - feel free to use WITH clause and add sum over..