# Query BETWEEN not working if it has the same date

Tags: php, oracle

I have an Oracle query that works fine using 'WHERE something BETWEEN FROM and TO' and if from/to are not the same, but when they are, it doesn't works.

I tried to validate on PHP if from/to are the same then i change the query replacing the BETWEEN for a 'WHERE something = date' but it doesn't works either.

**This is the query with the PHP validation i mentioned:**

```
<?php

$db   = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 191.238.210.61)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=opera)))";
$conn = oci_connect("opera", "opera", $db);

if (!$conn):
#--- Si no hay conexión, muestra error y detiene la depuración
    $m = oci_error();
    echo $m['message'];
elseif ($desde == $hasta):
    $consulta = "
                            SELECT
                                CONFIRMATION_NO,
                                NATIONALITY_DESC,
                                GUEST_NAME,
                                ADULTS,
                                CHILDREN,
                                RATE_CODE,
                                TRACE_ON,
                                DEPT_ID,
                                SUM(ADULTS) OVER()
                                || ' ADULTOS Y '
                                || SUM(CHILDREN) OVER()
                                || ' NIÑOS' AS RESULT
                            FROM
                            ( SELECT
                                MAX(CONFIRMATION_NO) AS CONFIRMATION_NO,
                                NATIONALITY_DESC,
                                GUEST_FIRST_NAME
                                || '  '
                                || GUEST_NAME GUEST_NAME,
                                MAX(ADULTS) AS ADULTS,
                                MAX(CHILDREN) AS CHILDREN,
                                RATE_CODE,
                                MIN(TRACE_ON) AS TRACE_ON,
                                LISTAGG(GUEST_RSV_TRACES.DEPT_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS DEPT_ID
                            FROM
                                GUEST_RSV_TRACES,
                                NAME_RESERVATION
                            WHERE trace_on = '$desde' 
                            AND guest_rsv_traces.resv_name_id = name_reservation.resv_name_id 
                            AND rate_code like 'ALL%' 
                            AND resv_status not in ('CANCELLED') 
                            AND guest_rsv_traces.dept_id not in ('TRF','OD')
                            GROUP BY
                            NATIONALITY_DESC,
                            GUEST_FIRST_NAME,
                            GUEST_NAME,
                            RATE_CODE
                            )
                            ";
    $query    = oci_parse($conn, $consulta);
    oci_execute($query);
elseif ($desde != $hasta):
    $consulta = "
                            SELECT
                                CONFIRMATION_NO,
                                NATIONALITY_DESC,
                                GUEST_NAME,
                                ADULTS,
                                CHILDREN,
                                RATE_CODE,
                                TRACE_ON,
                                DEPT_ID,
                                SUM(ADULTS) OVER()
                                || ' ADULTOS Y '
                                || SUM(CHILDREN) OVER()
                                || ' NIÑOS' AS RESULT
                            FROM
                            ( SELECT
                                MAX(CONFIRMATION_NO) AS CONFIRMATION_NO,
                                NATIONALITY_DESC,
                                GUEST_FIRST_NAME
                                || '  '
                                || GUEST_NAME GUEST_NAME,
                                MAX(ADULTS) AS ADULTS,
                                MAX(CHILDREN) AS CHILDREN,
                                RATE_CODE,
                                MIN(TRACE_ON) AS TRACE_ON,
                                LISTAGG(GUEST_RSV_TRACES.DEPT_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS DEPT_ID
                            FROM
                                GUEST_RSV_TRACES,
                                NAME_RESERVATION
                            WHERE trace_on BETWEEN '$desde' and '$hasta'
                            AND guest_rsv_traces.resv_name_id = name_reservation.resv_name_id 
                            AND rate_code like 'ALL%' 
                            AND resv_status not in ('CANCELLED') 
                            AND guest_rsv_traces.dept_id not in ('TRF','OD')
                            GROUP BY
                            NATIONALITY_DESC,
                            GUEST_FIRST_NAME,
                            GUEST_NAME,
                            RATE_CODE
                            )
                            ";
    $query = oci_parse($conn, $consulta);
    oci_execute($query);
endif;
?>
```

**Output example:** (Using BETWEEN '05-SEP-19' and '10-SEP-19'):

```
145580  EE.UU   JAMES LANTZKE   3   0   ALLIN5NMT   05/09/19    HK  6 ADULTOS Y 0 NIÑOS
167410  EE.UU   KATHARINE BLOOD 3   0   ALLIN5NMT   05/09/19    HK  6 ADULTOS Y 0 NIÑOS
```

**SUMMARY:**

1. If i do an (BETWEEN '05-SEP-19' and '10-SEP-19') it works
2. If i do an (BETWEEN '05-SEP-19' and '05-SEP-19') doesn't works
3. If i do an (trace_on = '05-SEP-19') doesn't works

I would like to know how i can query the same day using BETWEEN or a way to get results searching an specific date.

**¡Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates always have the components: year, month, day, hour, minute and second. User interfaces do not always show all these components (but they are still always there).

If your `TRACE_ON` column has the date `2019-09-05T12:34:56` and you are trying to see if it is `BETWEEN '05-SEP-19' AND '05-SEP-19'` then Oracle will (assuming that matches the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter) convert the string to a date at midnight and `2019-09-05T12:34:56 BETWEEN 2019-09-05T00:00:00 AND 2019-09-05T00:00:00` is false so the row will not be returned.

Change your query to:

```sql
SELECT
       -- ...
       TO_CHAR( TRACE_ON, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ),
       -- ...
 FROM (
  SELECT
          -- ...
  FROM    GUEST_RSV_TRACES
          INNER JOIN NAME_RESERVATION
          ON ( guest_rsv_traces.resv_name_id = name_reservation.resv_name_id )
  WHERE   trace_on >= TO_DATE( '$desde', 'DD-MON-RR' )
  AND     trace_on <  TO_DATE( '$hasta', 'DD-MON-RR' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  AND     -- ...
  GROUP BY
          -- ...
)
```

Comment: That was my problem and now works well !! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If column which is to be compared to those "dates" is of a `DATE` datatype, you shouldn't compare it to **strings**, because `'05-SEP-19'` (as well as all other values) are strings, not dates. Don't rely on implicit conversion - use either `to_date` function or date literal.

For example:

```
between date '2019-09-05' and date '2019-09-05'
```

or (presuming your NLS settings is set to English)

```
between to_date('05-sep-19', 'dd-mon-rr') and to_date('05-sep-19', 'dd-mon-rr')
```

Because, if you do it correctly, then between works as expected. Have a look:

```
SQL> create table test (id, datum) as
  2    select 1, date '2019-09-04' from dual union all
  3    select 2, date '2019-09-05' from dual union all   --> this ...
  4    select 3, date '2019-09-05' from dual union all   --> ... and this are between 05.09.2019 and 05.09.2019
  5    select 4, date '2019-09-06' from dual;

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From test
  2  where datum between date '2019-09-05' and date '2019-09-05';

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         2 05.09.2019
         3 05.09.2019

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, sadly it doesn't works and i don't know why, here the pic: https://ibb.co/KFqrSpW - a question my friend, i know the month needs to be un UPPERCASE so i tried with to_date('05-sep-19', 'dd-MON-rr') but doesn't works either, maybe it changes with the monthname on uppercase? i will be tuned

Comment: What is `trace_on` column's datatype? (by the way, letter case doesn't matter, "SEP" behaves the same as "sep")

Comment: ok i understand, thanks for the info. btw the column's datatype is: DATE, Nullable: No, Data Default: (null)

Comment: You're welcome. If it is DATE, then - as you've seen in demonstration I posted - such a query *works*, as far as Oracle is concerned.

Comment: yep, looks like the problem is other, do you see something weird?